# Could bitcoins be used to filter spam?

Tags: services

I would like filter spam in a way that people have to pay a very small amount of bitcoins to prioritize very good things or to kill very poor things, to make less casual environment and to encourage good filtering. Later best filterers could be rewarded with bitcoins. Is this possible or does this bloat the chain?

Comment: @mods: why did I receive mutual down-votes against all of my questions? 3-4 downvotes at the same short time.

Comment: You create a couple questions in a short amount of time that overlap themselves in what you are asking for, you don't try to explain clearly what you are asking when you first write your questions, quite often the questions are broad enough that they stop being related to Bitcoins, you ask multiple times for people to create tags for you, some of which don't have much to do with the questions you are asking and so forth. In short, you are acting spammy. I have voted your questions down as they, in my opinion, are below the standard for this StackExchange.

Comment: I have edited one of your questions into an example of how you could word everything, also turning my downvote into an upvote. For now, as I don't understand what exactly you are asking in some of the questions, I can't help you further without more discussion. I don't hold a grudge against you, so if someone will edit your questions into something more cohesive, I will reconsider my votes.

Comment: You don't need to worry about "bloating the chain". As long as you pay your transaction fees (you have to in order for miners to include your blocks), you're not "breaking the rules". If you pay for your bloat - it's not bloat.

Answer (score 3):

Using Bitcoins as a reward and micropayment system is possible. You wouldn't want to send a separate transaction for each micropayment (fee/transaction ratio would be quite big), but you can pay everyone down to a couple decimal places for each operation they make say, once a day.  Details of implementation would vary, depending on what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, as the size of a block increases above particular thresholds, the transaction fee required to include another transaction in a block goes up. This is by design to prevent bloating of the blockchain.

This would mean that trying to include many small transactions in a short period of time would either result in large transaction fees or delays in transactions being confirmed.

Even though Bitcoin is commonly spoken of as being great for micropayments, I don't believe that's literally true if you consider a micropayment to be in the order of a millionth of a bitcoin (micro meaning a millionth). Maybe it would be better said that it's great for millipayments?

Comment: "Micro" comes from the Greek word for "small". SI adopted it to denote one millionth, but it is still very widely used in the original meaning (microeconomics, microcomputer, microscope, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_micro-...). By the way, Bitcoin can be used for uBTC payments, but with replacements rather than raw transactions.

Answer (score 2):

A very similar idea already exists, see http://www.hashcash.org/. It requires proof of work to be send with every message, so spammers are paying by cpu-cycles.