# Defeating email spam with Bitcoin

Tags: academic-research, spam, micropayments, email

There was a paper somewhere proposing a scheme for filtering email spam with the use of Bitcoin micropayments. I can't remember where I saw it and can't find it now. Anybody knows about it?

Comment: related: [Could bitcoins be used to filter spam?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/could-bitcoins-be-used-to-filter-spam),  [BCT: "include messages in transaction, alternate use: anti spam email"](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=60272.0), [BCT: "Bounty proposal for a Bitcoin-based email to fight spam."](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=75933.0)

Answer (score 3):

[Hashcash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash) is one of the [many anti-spam techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques) used today, which is essentially a proof-of-work system designed to limit not only email spam but also denial-of-service attacks. A similar [proof-of-work](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_work) methodology is being used in bitcoin for block generation.

With an average of 150 billion e-mails sent out on a daily basis I cannot see how this could be deployed in the blockchain, which would then have to be adjusted to facilitate 1,7 million TPS while now it only serves 7 TPS (artificial limit).

Also, bitcoin is not really made for such small payments which would result in tons of useless and unspendable dust outputs.

Comment: I know about hascash and am aware of the scalability problems with Bitcoin being used for this. I'm only interested in the paper from a pure academical standpoint.